# CSS - Popup Layer (with overlay and close button)

Tags: css, overlay, layer

I do not know how to describe what I want.
So I did just draw it: http://i.imgur.com/oMFzJ.jpg

This is what I've got so far.
I do not know how to get this overlay

```
<div id="layer" style="background-color:#212121;border:2px solid #CCCCCC;width:450px;position:absolute;top:20%;left:20%;"> <iframe src="http://www.ebay.com" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe> <div style="width:100%;"><span style="color:#CCCCCC;float:right;font-size:11px;margin:3px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('layer').style.display='none';">Close X</span></div> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to make a *modal popup* would be to rely on an existing library to accomplish this, consider [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message)

In the future please provide more details on what has been tried etc.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) for my modal popups. The examples on the page use images but you can insert any HTML you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, but I need more like a code I've written (just edited my question)... just the overlay is missing

Comment: You need to format the code you posted to make it readable. Also, have you tried creating the overlay? There's nothing in what you've posted that would act as one.

Comment: ok. sorry, I am sooo stupid. I've fixed the problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: Lol, don't say that we've all made dumb mistakes. It comes with the territory ;) Glad you figured it out.